# Making query from template

Tags: python, html, django, templates, jinja2

I am using jinja2 as the templating engine for django app. I wanted to make query in the template. I tried doing this:

```
{% for f in fs %}
  {% Following.objects.filter(follows=f).count() %}
{% endfor %}
```

I'm passing 'fs' in variables while rendering the templates which a list.

But, its wrong. I can't do the 'query_set' call because of the way my models are defined. Here is a snippet:

```
class Following(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User)
  follows = models.ForeignKey(F)

class F(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

So, is there a possible way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jinja2 rather than the normal Django template language, what you have should work: you don't say why it doesn't.

But nevertheless, there's no need to define a separate method. You can use the automatic reverse relationship accessor:

```
{{ f.following_set.count() }}
```

Comment: Thanx. This is what I used : {{ f.following_set.count }}[No brackets after count]. And sorry, I mistakenly wrote jinja2, actually I'm using the normal Django template language.

Comment: Right, Django templates don't accept parentheses but call methods automatically, but in Jinja you do need the parens.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call methods that take parameter from django template. To overcome this, you can define method in your `F` model to get the required count.

For example:

```
class F(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  def get_follow_count(self):
      Following.objects.filter(follows=self).count()
```

Then in template you can do

```
{% for f in fs %}
  {{ f.get_follow_count }}
{% endfor %}
```